# Days in dataframe arent in order. How do I have it set to be the right order by the week?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

The days are shown in different order of appearance.  How do I have it so that they are correct?

```
# calculate the mode of week-day of members
mode_week_day_member = bike_data[bike_data['member_casual'] == 'member']
mode_week_day_member = mode_week_day_member['day_name'].mode()
mode_week_day_member

The output comes out like this:


0    Wednesday
Name: day_name, dtype: category
Categories (7, object): ['Friday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']
```

the data type has been defined as a category.

would like the days to come out as

'Sunday' , 'Monday' , 'Tuesday' , 'Wednesday' etc....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking reference from [pandas categorical data documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#reordering), you can reorder the categorical type:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["Wed", "Sun", "Tue", "Thu"], columns=["week_day"])
df["week_day"] = df["week_day"].astype("category")

[Out]:
  week_day
0      Wed
1      Sun
2      Tue
3      Thu
```

Define an order using `reorder_categories()` and sort the values; but make sure you have value for all weekdays, else you will get missing categorical value error:

```py
df = df["week_day"].cat.reorder_categories(["Sun", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu"], ordered=True).sort_values()

[Out]:
1    Sun
2    Tue
0    Wed
3    Thu
Name: week_day, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['Sun' < 'Tue' < 'Wed' < 'Thu']
```

Comment: @DavidL, did this solution work for you?